# Nodejs Passport authentication & local strategy not work through API Call

Tags: node.js, passport.js, postman, passport-local

> This is solved. Actually, the problem is with postman not on Passport code

I have a login system which is implemented through Nodejs Passport. For Login I use Handlebars for creating the UI and send the form data from frontend to backend.

These is my login Handlebars File

```
<form id="userloginform" method="post" action="/user/login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username or Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and on User.js file I have a code of authentication i.e like this

```
//Login Handler
passport.use('local-user', new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            console.log('error')
            logger.log('error', 'Error Generates on User.getUserByUsername Query on users.js file');
            throw err;
        }
        if(!user){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
        }
        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) {
                logger.log('error', 'Error Generates on User.comparePassword Query on users.js file');
                throw err;
            }
            if(isMatch){
                return done(null, user);
            }else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Credential, please check carefully...!'})
            }
        });
    });
  }
));

//Login Authentication
router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local-user', {
    failureRedirect: '/user/login',
    badRequestMessage: 'Field cannot be blank.!!', //missing credentials
    failureFlash: true
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('hello');

    req.flash('success_msg', 'Welcome ' + req.user.name);
    req.flash('custom_msg', token);
    //res.redirect('/success?username='+req.user.username);
    res.redirect('/user/dashboard');
  });
```

All these things are working pefectly.

> Now when I call it through postman and pass two parameters i.e username and password then it does nothing. Simply failure redirect.

I have done this through proper nodejs with form submitted pattern. Now I want to be done through API from different Server.

Anyone have any idea then let me know. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you use `console.log` instead of `req.flash`?

Comment: Its done. Actually I am passing my data on form-Data on postman. On that we have to pass our data on x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: How can I remove the question as currently it will not be used

Comment: don't remove the question, someone will benefit from it.
Just edit it so the problem is clear that it was a postman issue.
Also, add a postman tag.

Comment: okay dear. And thanks for suggest...

Comment: I want to use req, res on passport local strategy for sending the json response to API.How can I do this?